# Create a matrix with another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

So, I have a dataset (usage) that is like the following, in R:

```
Item    Bike    Usage
item1   bike1   1
item2   bike1   2
item1   bike2   1
item3   bike2   2
```

And I wanted to convert on a matrix with the usage. 
I created a matrix where my header is the bikes (bike 1, bike2), and the row names is (item 1, item 2, item 3), and filled with NA and now I want to fill it the usage, such as:

```
bike1  bike2
item 1 1      1
item 2 1      0
item 3 0      1
```

I created the following loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(usage)) {
  item<-usage[i,1]
  bike<-usage[i,2]
  matriz[item,bike]<-usage[i,3]

matriz[is.na(matriz)]<-0

}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, item, bike, value = list(Usage = 6)) : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try `xtabs` if you need table

```
res_tb <- xtabs(Usage~.,df)
```

such that

```
> res_tb
       Bike
Item    bike1 bike2
  item1     1     1
  item2     2     0
  item3     0     2
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Item = c("item1", "item2", "item1", "item3"), 
    Bike = c("bike1", "bike1", "bike2", "bike2"), Usage = c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(dat, "Item", names_from="Bike",
            values_from="Usage", values_fill=list(Usage=0))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Item  bike1 bike2
#   <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 item1     1     1
# 2 item2     2     0
# 3 item3     0     2
```

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Item = c("item1", "item2", "item1", "item3"), 
    Bike = c("bike1", "bike1", "bike2", "bike2"), Usage = c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is `acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df,  Item ~ Bike, fill = 0)
#       bike1 bike2
#item1     1     1
#item2     2     0
#item3     0     2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Item = c("item1", "item2", "item1", "item3"), 
    Bike = c("bike1", "bike1", "bike2", "bike2"), Usage = c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```